# Create bare rails controller class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, actioncontroller

I'm trying to create clean controller based on `ActionController::Base`. That's what I try:

```
class MetalController
   ActionController::Base.without_modules(:ParamsWrapper, :Streaming).each do |left|
     include left
   end
end
```

From Rails doc:

> Shortcut helper that returns all the modules included in
>     ActionController::Base except the ones passed as arguments:
>
> This gives better control over what you want to exclude and makes it
>     easier to create a bare controller class, instead of listing the modules
>     required manually.

My another controller inherits from `MetalController` :

```
class API::BaseController < MetalController
  #.... my awesome api code
end
```

So this not work then i launch `rails server`:

> `block in <module:AssetPaths>': undefined method`config_accessor' for
>   MetalController:Class (NoMethodError)

Rails 4.1.0, Ruby 2.1.0

### Update:

If i `include ActiveSupport::Configurable`

throws the errors:

> `_implied_layout_name': undefined local variable or method`
>   controller_path' for MetalController:Class (NameError)

Comment: Have you tried adding `include ActiveSupport::Configurable` to your MetalController (before your each loop)?

Comment: @BroiSatse not work (. look update questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit from `ActionController::Metal`:

```
class MetalController < ActionController::Metal
  ActionController::Base.without_modules(:ParamsWrapper, :Streaming).each do |left|
    include left
  end
end
```

Comment: i dont think so, because order in `ActionController::Base::MODULES` look same as `ActionController::Base.without_modules(:ParamsWrapper, :Streaming)`. i know about `.ancestors`, thank for you solutions but i have same errors.

Comment: Hmmm. It is running for me without any problems.

Comment: Sorry i have another errors `_implied_layout_name': undefined local variable or method `controller_path' for MetalController:Class` after you solutions, have idea?

Comment: You need to inherit from AbstractController::Base as well. I'll update answer.

Comment: i found solution i need inherit from `ActionController::Metal` if i use `AbstractController::Base` instead my controller ```raise undefined method `action'```

Comment: Awesome. I'll delete this answer, please post yours. :)